# Background image doesn't fit in the screen width

Tags: html, css, background-image, background-size

I've set my background image (1280 x 853) and that doesn't suit well the screen.

How can I fix that?

```
body {
  background-image: url("/assets/pic.jpg");
}
```

Comment: try `background-image: url("/assets/pic.jpg"); background-size:cover`

Comment: try `background-size: 100% 100%`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
body {
    background-image:  url("/assets/pic.jpg");
    background-size:   cover;   
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: You can also optionally set background-position: center center;
Dont forget to mark answer right if I've helped! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
body {
    background-image: url("/assets/pic.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
}
```

And optionally set `background-repeat: no-repeat` to prevent to image from repeating.

[Here's a example.](http://jsfiddle.net/3vodzdg1/)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to background-size: cover, you can use the background-position property to place your image where you want it to be, as sometimes background-size:cover will cut off areas that you wanted to be visible. Using percentage values in the background-position property will allow you to fine tune this more.